# Unable to connect to redis cluster on kubernetes from my golang application deployed within the same cluster

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, redis-cluster

I deployed a redis cluster on Kubernetes with bitnami helm charts (https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster).

I can successfully connect to the Redis cluster from within the Kubernetes cluster by running the below commands:

1. `kubectl run my-redis-release-client --rm -it --image docker.io/bitnami/redis:4.0.11-debian-9 -- bash`
2. `redis-cli -h redis-cluster-0.redis-cluster-headless.redis`

But I am unable to connect to redis cluster from my golang application deployed within the same cluster.

The redis connection string uri I used on my golang application is "redis://redis-cluster-0.redis-cluster-headless.redis:6379". This is following the "redis-pod-name.redis-service-name.namespace" convention.

NOTE: I want to be able to access the redis cluster from only within the Kubernetes cluster. I don’t want to grant external access. Please help...

Comment: "But I am unable to connect to redis cluster from my golang application deployed within the same cluster." What error are you getting, exactly?

Comment: When i run kubectl logs <application-pod-name>. I get "Unable to connect to redis server" error. So basically connection is timing out.

Comment: That's not very helpful, I guess the application should be a bit more detailed about what happened, e.g. "could not resolve DNS name" / "connection refused" / "connection timed out" etc.

Comment: It seems you are using the `redis-cli` command interactively in the pod which will obviously work. Expose the port from pod to access it internally. Check https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run for more info.

Comment: Have you exposed any service for redis ?

Comment: You mean using kubectl expose? I haven't. I am only using the headless service for now

Answer (score 0):

`Headless` service is if you don't need load-balancing and a single Service IP. `Headless` service is not *for accessing the redis cluster from only within the Kubernetes cluster*

You can create a service to expose redis. Below is an example to create a `ClusterIP` type which *only let's you connect to it from within the cluster and not from outside the cluster*.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
```

The pod or deployment of redis need to have matching label `app: redis`

Then you can connect to it using `redis.default.svc.cluster.local:6379` to connect to it from Golang app.